# Java delete file/directory equivalent of linux "rm -rf /tmp/garbagedir*"

Tags: java, linux, file-io

Given a bunch of tmp directories and tmp files like this:

```
/tmp/garbagedir1/
/tmp/garbagedir2/
/tmp/garbagedir3/
/tmp/deleteme.txt
/tmp/deleteme.log
```

In Linux, we can execute one simple shell command to recursively force delete all of these:

```
$ rm -rf /tmp/garbagedir* /tmp/deleteme*
```

All of the above files and directories are deleted, including all the files that may be in the directories.  All other files in the /tmp directory are not touched.

There are many ways to do this in Java, but what is the simplest way that does not involve lots of Java style boilerplate code and still be platform independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new file API has all the tools you need:

- it has a [method accepting globs as arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-);
- it has a `FileVisitor` interface which you can use to perform recursive file deletion (see [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/working-with-java-7-file-api-recursive.html) for an example).

Feel free to salvage the recursive deletion example, and note that it can be improved. In particular, this one will stop at the first deletion error, but it is trivial to modify so that it *continues* in this case instead.

Comment: I'll take a look at this.  This almost feels like something that should be in a library somewhere, maybe something like FileUtils.forceDeletePath("/tmp/garbagedir*");

Comment: @Gary it is indeed strange enough that `Files` does not have a recursive deletion method... That sounds like an obvious thing to have. But it probably isn't. How to deal with errors, for instance...

Comment: Right.  Sometimes IO errors are important.  In my case, I don't care.  Netier does "rm -rf".

Comment: @Gary well, you _do_ get a non 0 return code if `rm -rf` fails to delete at least one file; as I said, tune to your needs ;)

Comment: @Gary there is another point: when using the `rm` command, it is not it which performs glob expansion but the shell!

Comment: I am probably going to use a solution very similar to this.  I added a method to your class so I can use it like this:  DeletionFileVisitor.deletePath(Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")),"garbagedir*")

Answer (score 2):

you may use the FileUtils class of Apache Commons IO; with it you can do something like that:

```
FileUtils.forceDelete(new File("/home/test"));
```

Links to the documentation: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Hope it helps

Angelo

Comment: Right.  That would work fine if the complete name of the file is known in advance. The File() object doesn't really deal with filename globbing or some regex very well.

Answer (score 1):

Note, I haven't tested this code so don't try it first on anything important!

You can use the Java NIO2 SimpleFileVisitor to recursviely walk thru directories and their children.  First we create a new FileVisitor that will delete all files that it sees and then delete the empty directories once all its children have been deleted.

```
  FileVisitor recursiveDeleteVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

  @Override
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
          BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

      System.out.println("Deleting file: " + file);
      Files.delete(file);
      return CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
          IOException exc) throws IOException {

      System.out.println("Deleting dir: " + dir);
      if (exc == null) {
          Files.delete(dir);
          return CONTINUE;
      } else {
          throw exc;
      }
  }

 };
```

This might count as boiler plate, but you would only have to write the `FileVisitor` instance once and then you can re-use it as part of a utility class. I'm not sure why something like this isn't included in the JDK.

Anyway, once you have that, then iterate over the children of `/tmp` and recursively delete any directories that match:

```
 File root = new File("/tmp");
 for(File child : root.listFiles()){
      //optionally use Pattern class for regex
      if(child.getName().startsWith("garbagedir")){
          Files.walkFileTree(child.toPath(), recursiveDeleteVisitor);
      }
 }
```

**EDIT**

---

User fge pointed out that Java 7 has a `Files.newDirectoryStream()` method that will return a `DirectoryStream` object that can be used to iterate over the children instead of using the old `File.listFiles()` which returns an array which means all the objects are created in memory before iteration.  This could save you from memory problems if you have lots of files.  You can even use the *globbing* pattern as a 2nd String argument.

```
Path root = Paths.get("/tmp");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(root, "garbagedir*")) {
   for (Path entry: stream) {
       Files.walkFileTree(child.toPath(), recursiveDeleteVisitor);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why on earth use `File` instead of `Path`? Use `Paths.get()`!

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in Java 7 yet, but I couldn't find a Path equivalent to File.listFiles(). `Paths.get()` implies you know the name of the child file(s) where as `listFiles()` does not.  That means (to me) one would have to use the FileVisitor methods.  To avoid confusion of which FileVisitor was used when and to simplify the FileVisitor I provided so it only deletes and doesn't keep state of which files to delete/keep.  I went with the easier to understand example.

Comment: Look at `Files.newDirectoryStream(*)`... Unlike `listFiles()`, this will produce a _stream_; therefore you won't eat memory needlessly if you have 100k+ files in a directory ;)